# Compress contacts onto iPhone (without iCloud)

Tags: iphone, contacts, google, contacts.app

I have contacts from several google accounts I would like to merge onto my iPhone local contact list, and eventually completely remove the Google dependency.  I spoke with a Genius about this today who said I would have to do some coding for this.  Is there a first party way to compress and sync contacts across the iPhone and Google accounts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't do this.  It is not possible.

Comment: Not true.  Several apps on the iOS app store are useful to accomplish this.  I hve experience with one called 'Contact Mover', by Playa Apps.  Allows you to merge in either direction from any account the phone can see.